# Problem when importing from another folder in React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following folder structure

[image]

I want to import both MessageList.tsx and MessageSent.tsx inside my Chat.tsx

```
// Chat.tsx
import React from 'react'
import {MessageList, MessageSent} from "./components/"

type Props = {}

const Chat= (props: Props) =\> {
return (
<div\>Chat</div>
)
}

export default Chat`


// MessageSent.tsx
import React from 'react'

type Props = {}

const MessageList = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>MessageList</div>
  )
}

export default MessageList
```

MessageList.tsx is similar to MessageSent,tsx, only the name of the components is different

However, when I try to do the import of these two components {MessageList, MessageSent} I get the following error:

** Cannot find module './components/' or its corresponding type declarations.**

Why is that?

Tried different paths besides "./components/", even with full path.

Comment: You need `index.ts` with exports from both `MessageList.tsx` and `MessageSent.tsx` file in the `components` folder

Answer (score 2):

You can either import the components one by one

```
import MessageSent from "./components/MessageSent"
import MessageList from "./components/MessageList"
```

or create an index directory file (index.ts)

```
import MessageSent from './MessageSent'
import MessageList from './MessageList'
export { MessageSent, MessageList }
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be working. 
I believe the only solution so I don't have to create an index.ts file inside the components folder is to import them one by one.
Why is this index.ts file required and you simply can't import them directly?

Comment: @SpamSpasmodium Import keyword will look for explicit specified file or index file in a folder. So, the code you write will look for components/index.ts, but since you doesn't have that file, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to import from components you need index.ts file in components folder.

```
// index.ts
export * from './MessageList';
export * from './MessageSent';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new file named `index.ts` inside your components folder
Then write this in the `index.ts`

```js
export * from './MessageList.tsx';
export * from './MessageSent.tsx';
```